Is there a way to control the number of points per node when writing to COPC
I'm trying to write a very large (6TB) collection of LAZ files into a collection of COPC files. When viewing these remotely using a webviewer, I'm running into performance issues when the viewer has to gather large point chunks.
Is there a way to control the number of points per node when writing COPC files?
I've looked at Untwine and PDAL and neither seems to accept any arguments to control this aspect of the COPC writing process, i.e. the part that selects which points go into which octree node.

There is currently no way to adjust the node threshold with either Untwine or PDAL. Please provide a pull request in either repository that implements it, but do know adjusting it could involve more than modifying a single parameter.

There is a compile-time value in Untwine that you could play with, but if you have fewer points in a node, you'll have more nodes, so, in order to see the same thing in a viewer, you're going to have to fetch the points no matter what.
